# How to extract a value from a list in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a dataframe and looks like this:

```
         0             1
  0      0    [03/25/93]
  1      1     [6/18/85]
  2      2      [7/8/71]
  3      3     [9/27/75]
  4      4      []
  5      5      []
```

How can I extract the value inside the list in another column of the DataFrame???

```
         0             1
  0      0    03/25/93
  1      1    6/18/85
  2      2    7/8/71
  3      3    9/27/75
  4      4      NaN
  5      5      Nan
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you get it? Maybe exist another better solution for prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str[0]`:

```
df[1] = df[1].str[0]
print (df)
   0         1
0  0  03/25/93
1  1   6/18/85
2  2    7/8/71
3  3   9/27/75
4  4       NaN
5  5       NaN
```